# What Gates/Wing of the Terminal at Schiphol for KLM's Alitalia Flights to Rome?

Tags: ams, klm, code-share, airport-terminals

Does anyone know the typical wing of the Schiphol terminal where Alitalia flights depart for Fiumicino Airport outside of Roma?

Comment: It will be in the 'within Schengen part' of the airport. I have never flown with the company, so I do not know more details.

Comment: @pnuts I'm guessing a code share flight.

Comment: KLM or Alitalia? Which one is the operating airline?

Comment: Alitalia in partnership with KLM.

Answer (score 2):

B, C or higher number D gates (54+ if I'm not mistaken) in Schengen area. I flew to Rome on Delta and Alitalia flights **operated by KLM** from all three of them, and KLM has great flexibility in shifting gates around.

However if you have a flight **operated by Alitalia**, the only one I was on departed from C gates both times I took it. This is further confirmed by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amsterdam_Airport_Schiphol#Passenger) (credit to @pnuts for the link).